# Does any Christian denomination consider the Quran as inspired?

Tags: islam, quran

The main difference between Christianity and Islam is the acceptance of the Quran as an inspired revelation.

Most or all Christian denominations/sects refuse the Quran believing that it be uninspired and fabricated. My question is not about all those denominations.

Present Islam (both, Sunni and Shia) on their side accepts Jesus as a Messenger of God but usually doubts the reliability of Christian scriptures, and thus ignores many parts of the Message that has come to us through Jesus (p.b.u.h). This may be a reason for convinced Christians not to accept Islam as is.

However, the Quran itself clearly accepts that Jesus is a Messenger of God, a Prophet, and the Messiah that will return (it is not clearer in the Quran than in the Bible whether he would come much before or almost with the Last Day).

Hence, it may be a Christian position to refuse present Islam not because of a general refusal of the Quran but rather because present Islam does not consider the Word of God come through Jesus (p.b.u.h) and his importance in an appropriate way.

My question:

Is there any Christian denomination that considers the Quran as inspired but refuses Islam as it is?

Comment: This question has a rather obvious answer. Islam is derived from the Quaran. The Quaran teaches that Christianity is false. So any Christian who thinks the Quaran is Gods word is ignorant, foolish, or blind.

Comment: The Quran rejects some Christian teachings but it confirms the message Of God obtained through Jesus. I understand that a denomination parting from this is Islam, as Christianity seems to define itself rather through the rejection of the Quran than through the acceptance of the Word of God received through Jesus (p.b.u.h)

Comment: it’s not just some Christian teaching. It denies essentially the crux of Christian orthodoxy, that Jesus (who is God) died, was buried, and resurrected on the third day, was seen by his disciples, and ascended to the right hand of God.

Comment: @ Luke Hill I think the denial of the crucifixion is an error in the interpretation of the Quran, and the statement that Jesus is God is an error in the interpretation of the Gospel.

Comment: I don’t know how you could possibly interpret it another way. “And [for] their saying, "Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus the son of Mary, the messenger of Allāh." And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him;” that seems pretty clear. Also John 1:1 and other verses in the gospel accounts clearly mark Jesus as God incarnate.

Comment: @Jeschu *and the statement that Jesus is God is an error in the interpretation of the Gospel* For Trinitarians, no, for some sects like the Jehovah's Witnesses, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have initially pointed out, the main and original difference between Christians and Muslim is that Christians redoubt the inspired nature of the Quran.

Nevertheless, there is a group/movement/denomination that may be counted among Christians that partially accepts the Quran as inspired, along with other religious teachings but who see the capability of humans to receive revelation submitted to human limitations.
This is the Universal Unitarian movement,
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarian_Universalism?wprov=sfla1.

For the syncretism of the philosophy or religion, it's not unanimously seen as a Christian denomination, and their acceptance of the Quran is certainly not the way as in Islam.

I do not know any Christian church that accepts the Quran as an inspired writing.

Answer (score 1):

**Does any Christian denomination consider the Quran as inspired?**

The short answer is **no**.

Although certain truths may be found in all major religions, including Islam, no Christian denominations believe the Quran (Koran) as being inspired (from God).

Christians should have a respect for Quran and the beliefs of Muslims, but do not compromise Christian beliefs that the Quran is is inspired from God. From a Christian point of view it is not.

Catholics, for example do not believe that the Quran is inspired, yet acknowledges that there are some truths within Islamic faith or other non-Christian religion, for that matter.

> The Catholic Church rejects nothing that is true and holy in these religions. - [***Nostra Aetate***](https://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decl_19651028_nostra-aetate_en.html)

Nevertheless, the [**Catholic Encyclopedia**](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08692a.htm) explains the six sources from which the Quran seems to be based on.

> **The sources of the Koran be reduced to six:**
>
> - The Old Testament (canonical and apocryphal) and the hybrid Judaism of the late rabbinical schools. During Mohammed's time the Jews were numerous in many parts of Arabia, especially around Medina. Familiarity with them is undoubtly responsible for many Old Testament stories alluded to in Koran. Later Judaism and Rabbinism are equally well represented (Geiger, "Was hat Mohammed aus dem Judenthum aufgenommen?", Wiesbaden, 1833; tr. "Judaism and Islam", Madras, 1898).
> - The New Testament (canonical and apocryphal) and various heretical doctrines. On his journeys between Syria, Hijaz, and Yemen, Mohammed had every opportunity to come in close touch with Yemenite, Abyssinian, Ghassanite, and Syrian Christians, especially heretic. Hence, while the influence of orthodox Christianity upon the Koran has been slight, apocryphal and heretical Christian legends, on the other hand, are one of the original sources of Koranic faith. (See Muir, op. cit. infra, 66-239; Tisdall, "The Original Sources of the Qur'an", London, 1905, 55-211.)
> - Sabaism, a combination of Judaism, Manicheism, and old disfigured Babylonian heathenism.
> - Zoroastrianism. On account of Persia's political influence in the north-eastern part of Arabia, it is natural to find Zoroastrian elements in the Koran.
> - [Hanifism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanif), the adherents of which, called Hanifs, must have been considerable in number and influence, as it is known from contemporary Arabian sources that twelve of Mohammed's followers were members of this sect.
> - Native ancient and contemporary Arabian heathen beliefs and practices. Wellhausen has collected in his "Reste des arabischen Heidentums" (Berlin, 1897) all that is known of pre-Islamic Arabian heathen belief, traditions, customs, and superstitions, many of which are either alluded to or accepted and incorporated in the Koran. From the various sects and creeds, and Abul-Fida, the well-known historian and geographer of the twelfth century, it is clear that religious beliefs and practices of the Arabs of Mohammed's day form one of the many sources of Islam. From this heathen source Islam derived the practices of polygamy and slavery, which Mohammed sanctioned by adopting them.

Other Christian sources may be perused at one’s leisure in the following articles:

- [**A Simple Reason why the Qur’an cannot be the Word of God**](https://crossexamined.org/simple-reason-quran-word-god/)
- [**Is the Qur'an the Word of God?**](https://www.eauk.org/church/resources/theological-articles/is-the-quran-the-word-of-god.cfm) Evangelical
- [**Criticism of the Quran (Wikipedia)**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_the_Quran) See: ***Preexisting sources***